# Git not pulling files in the repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository in the server, I have to push and pull my data into it. When i tried to pull on one instance a lot of my files got deleted even though it is present in the repository. The commands I have used are given below

```
git add .
git add -u
git commit -m 'comments'
git pull origin master
```

This is what happens in the terminal on running these commands

```
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git add .
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git add -u
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git commit -m 'with add ads'
[master 5706969] with add ads
Committer: Manesh <manesh@sysadmin-PC.(none)>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

git commit --amend --reset-author

10 files changed, 523 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
create mode 100755 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Controller/AdsController.php
create mode 100644 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Entity/Ads.php
create mode 100644 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Entity/AdsRepository.php
create mode 100644          src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm/Ads.orm.xml
create mode 100755 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/views/Ads/addads.html.twig
create mode 100755 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/views/Ads/index.html.twig
mode change 100644 => 100755 src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/views/Logs/index.html.twig
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git pull origin master
git@192.168.10.241's password: 
remote: Counting objects: 50, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
remote: Total 28 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (28/28), done.
From 192.168.10.241:/var/www/repositories/Mobpaz/MobpazAdmin
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD  
Auto-merging src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/views/base.html.twig
Auto-merging src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/views/Logs/index.html.twig
Auto-merging src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in   src/Mobpaz/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git add .
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git add -u
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git commit -m 'with add ads'
[master 0c0e548] with add ads
Committer: Manesh <manesh@sysadmin-PC.(none)>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

git commit --amend --reset-author

manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git commit -m 'with add ads'
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
manesh@sysadmin-PC:/var/www/MobpazAdmin$ git pull origin master
git@192.168.10.241's password: 
From 192.168.10.241:/var/www/repositories/Mobpaz/MobpazAdmin
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I resolved the conflict that occurred in the first pull before doing the second.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong this happens often hence my work is getting interrupted after every push and pull.

My issue is that even the files that is there in the repository is deleted from my local copy.

Comment: i see couple issues , like the git is not configured properly. you want to read `git config` and if you `edit` and then `commit` and do immediate `pull` git will warn you for `auto merge`  - in the simplest terms, git pull does a git fetch followed by a git merge.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking what `commit` does compared to `push`.

`commit` creates a local staging area for you to work with. This is completely local, and your git server has no notion of these changes.

When you `push` your changes (after `commit`ting), your server will then hold your changes.

Sorry if I am incorrect here, your logs just don't have any `push` calls.

Comment: if i commit and pull it will merge all the files in repository with my  local repository right?

Comment: Yes, but your local changes will not be reflected on the remote repository until you `push`.